# Session variable in html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, session-variables

I have an index.html which contains a login form. When user submits it proceeds to login.php and when the user is verified, It heads back to index.html. The verified username is stored in a session variable called username. So I want that username to be shown at the top of my index.html.
Something like 'Hi ' or 'Hi Guest' if session variable is empty.
Please help.

UPDATE: I think ajax or jquery can help to retrieve that session variable.  Plum ' s idea should work but isn't. So I request to post full fledged files.
Thanks.

Comment: Read about [session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) in PHP.

Comment: You can't use sessions, or any PHP for that matter, in a `.html` file, it has to be a `.php` file (unless your instruct the server to parse PHP in `.html` files too specifically). You can use a tenary operator, like this to achieve what you want in PHP: `echo "Hi, ".(isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : "guest");`

Answer (score 1):

Add an php page like check-session.php and put the following code

```
<?php 

if(!session_id())session_start();
$sessVal=isset($_SESSION['guest']) ? $_SESSION['guest'] : null;

echo $sessVal; ?>
```

and underneath the index.html page put this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("check-session.php", function(data, status){

    if(data)
    $("#guestContainer").html('Hi'+data);
    else
    $("#guestContainer").html(null);

});});
```

This jquery load function will show the guest's name.

Comment: you should put "Hi Guest" in a div container like <div id="guestContainer"></div>. put your javascript code after jquery library. <script>//jquery library </script> and then the rest of $(document)..etc..

Comment: I've put everything as you said,It's not working. I've tried by making a different html too.

Comment: Please post a full fledged html file with nothing extra except a working one. As I said the session variable is 'username'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo 'hi guest';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

then try this

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo 'hi '.$_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
    echo 'hi guest';
}
```